# fadein() and fadeout() all child tags at once

Tags: jquery, css

I have 5 span elements that I am trying to fade in and out on top of an image. The following code works fine if I have no child html elements included in the span tag, but if I add p tags around some of the elements, it doesn't work. The reason I am adding p tags is I would like the text stacked on top of each other instead of inline so it fits in the area I am trying to display on.

How can I make the jQuery work again now that I have added the p tags?

**EDIT** To clarify, I only want one span to show at a time. On page load, first span shows, then when it fades out, the second span shows up, and so on. I can get it where the p tags fade in and out individually, but would rather the span tag fade as one.

Would it be better to use CSS somehow to stack the text? (I am very bad at CSS)

**HTML**

```
 <span class="my-text"><p>Some long </p> Text</span>
 <span class="my-text"><p>Some long </p> Text</span>
 <span class="my-text"><p>Some long </p> Text</span>
 <span class="my-text"><p>Some long </p> Text</span>
 <span class="my-text"><p>Some long </p> Text that goes <p>farther</p></span>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
var quoteIndex = -1,
quotes = jQuery('.my-text');

function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .delay(2000)
        .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
}
showNextQuote();
});
```

Comment: Basically, different browsers handle some edge cases differently, though in this case chrome seems to format it properly, even though you are placing a block element inside of an inline element.

Comment: Your code appears to be working as-is in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/apgr9/

Comment: @KevinB, OP wants <p> tags to fade in and out as well.

Comment: I updated my post. I should have clarified I want only one span to show at a time.

Comment: Use divs, not spans. http://jsfiddle.net/jGmnz/

Comment: `<p>` inside `<span>` - that's a block element inside an inline element! I expect jQuery is doing its best but things are failing at the basic HTML level. "Block in block", "inline in block", or "inline in inline" are OK but "block in inline" kind of illogical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not put block level elements (`p`) inside inline ones (`span`) - that's invalid.

Try this instead - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/apgr9/2/)

***HTML***

```
<div class="my-text"><p>Some long </p> Text 1</div>
```

***jQuery***

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var quoteIndex = -1,
    quotes = jQuery('.my-text');

    jQuery(".my-text:gt(0)").hide();    

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }
    showNextQuote();
});
```

Comment: And even when I knew it was invalid, I still tried to make it work. Why do I do things late at night??? Thank you.